# Nginx: location and rewrite both for similar pattern challenge

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Google search console reported that my site has many non existing URLs which is belongs to blog posts and throwing 404 on request.

Also we recently updated the site's permalinks for blog posts for better SEO and segregate posts.

To get rid of this I redirected old permalinks to new rule and non existing 404 pages to return 410 status.

Here's the work:

```
server {
    # ...
    # 1. Return "410 Gone" to all non-existing blog posts, which follows old permalink style
    #    So requests like below will be served with status code 410
    #    /family-tour-packages-are-coming-soon-315/
    #    /black-bikers-team-won-the-match-yesterday-1116/
    location ~* ^/[a-z0-9-]+-(315|1116|1104|311|341|339)/?$ {
        return 410;
    }

    # 2. Re-direct old permalink style to new style prefixed with /category-slug
    #    /post will be replaced by /category-slug by back-end script
    #    Actually 2 redirect will be made always on old permalink request
    #    So requests like: /kia-motors-shares-jump-after-report-apple-to-invest-3-6-billion-2248/
    #    will be redirected by Nginx to /post/kia-motors-shares-jump-after-report-apple-to-invest-3-6-billion-2248/
    #    and back-end script will finally redirect to /news/kia-motors-shares-jump-after-report-apple-to-invest-3-6-billion-2248/
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\-[\d]+)/?$ /post/$1/ redirect;
    # ...
}
```

But in this case `location` block is being ignored and rewrite rule is taking place always.

What can I do to return 410 for specific match and redirect for others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `rewrite` rule in `location /` block. This way nginx selects the `location` first and then applies the rules for that `location`.

Comment: Thank this works. Alternatively I redirected all to home page instead returning 410;

Answer (score 0):

Above answer by Tero Kilkanen worked perfectly.

Additionally I found another way to fix. Rather than returning 410, I just redirected them all to home (/). So, I changed code like this:

```
# From this
location ~* ^/[a-z0-9-]+-(315|1116|1104|311|341|339)/?$ {
    return 410;
}

# to this
rewrite ^/[a-z0-9-]+-(315|1116|1104|311|341|339)/?$ / redirect;
```

Here's the final one:

```
server {
    # ...
    rewrite ^/[a-z0-9-]+-(315|1116|1104|311|341|339)/?$ / permanent;
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\-[\d]+)/?$ /post/$1/ permanent;
    # ...
}
```

Comment: It is better to use `location` blocks than `rewrite` statements.